# Only Getting User Name and ID

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using codeigniter and implementing Facebook PHP SDK into my website for user be able to login into.

Eveything went well, but I just don't know why I only able to get their name and id.

Here is the code for my library I've got from somewhere:

```
public function login_url() {
  return $this->helper->getLoginUrl( $this->permissions );
}

/**
 * Returns the current user's info as an array.
 */
public function get_user() {
  if ( $this->session ) {
    /**
     * Retrieve Userâ€™s Profile Information
     */
    // Graph API to request user data
    $request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me' ) )->execute();

    // Get response as an array
    $user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    return $user;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And here is my controller:

Fisrt it direct from my website to Facebook

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library('facebook');
    redirect($this->facebook->login_url());
}
```

And then facebook redirect it back to my website (myweb.com/index.php/getUSer)

```
public function getUser() {

    $this->load->library('facebook');
    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($user); 

}
```

However the result is only:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Iyal
    [id] => 143426842340043
)
```

My question is, How to get the full information of the user, such as the email address, profil picture, and etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked back with the organization that you got your Facebook "library" from? It seems like their request call is out of date and they might have an update that you can use, or verify the issue with them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Login/Registration with Codeigniter - user data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337807/facebook-login-registration-with-codeigniter-user-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default when retrieving a user's profile via the Facebook API a limited set of fields are returned such as the ones you are getting.

You must include the fields you wish to get information from in your request to the Graph API. A list of profile fields is available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).

What you need to do is add these additional fields to the request made in your library using the method demonstrated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile/5.0.0).

For instance in your situation if you wanted to get a user's email address in addition to the standard data you could add a method like this in your library:

```
public function get_userWithEmail() {
    if ( $this->session ) {
    /**
    * Retrieve Userâ€™s Profile Information
    */
    // Graph API to request user data
    $request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,name,email' ) )->execute();

    // Get response as an array
    $user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    return $user;
  }
  return false;
}
```

*Please note that the version of the API your library targets is an old version.* You may be better off rewriting it to work with the latest version to ensure it is supported into the future. The documents [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0) give a pretty good overview and it should be obvious enough which parts of the library to change whilst retaining the original structure.

Comment: `fields=id,name,email` Damn, it works. Is there any thing else beside email. Please list it all to me.

Comment: I've linked to a document which lists all of the fields in the second paragraph.

Comment: Can you please give me the newest library for this, please. A complete library.

Comment: It's available [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/archive/5.0-dev.zip), and the link to the docs for using it are [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0).

Comment: Thank you very much for all of that links.